# import a oracle dumpfile

Tags: oracle, datapump, oracle-dump

I have an oracle dump file which I assume has been created using the exp command and not the `expdp`

The dump file is about 4 GB and I would like to import it into my Oracle 11.2 database.

The dump file which was created has the tablespace as "spaceA" but my tablespace is "spaceB"

So I would need to remap the tablespace as well.

I did use impdp commands before and it used to work perfectly fine but guess as I understand
impdp could only be used on dump file if it was exported using expdp..

Since I am not very familiar with the process of exporting/importing, I would like to get help with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tablespace is not hardcoded in the dmp file create table statements then you should be able to import without a problem. So my suggestion would be to first try something like the following (for more details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10701/original_import.htm)

```
imp user/password@instance file=FILE.dmp log=LOG.log fromuser=DMPSCHEMA touser=NEWSCHEMA
```

If you get IMP-00017 errors. Then you have to take the longer route. You need to first create the tables and then import with ignore=y.

To first create the tables you need the DDL statements, which you can obtain by running:

```
imp user/password@instance file=FILE.dmp log=LOG.log full=y indexfile=INDEXFILE.log
```

The INDEXFILE.log will contain all the create table statements. Find and replace "spaceA" with "spaceB", create the tables, and then run the import with the ignore=y parameter which will ignore table creation errors (since tables already exist) and load data:

```
imp user/password@instance file=FILE.dmp log=LOG.log fromuser=DMPSCHEMA touser=NEWSCHEMA ignore=y
```